# Can't delete role even though bot has admin permissions?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I clearly have the permissions to delete the role, but I still get the error:

```
await test_role.delete()
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

checking bot permissions gives me every role as true (which it should bc it's an admin), but just to verify that I have manage roles permissions:

```
for _ in guild.me.guild_permissions:
        print(_)

>>>> ...
>>>> ('manage_roles', True)
>>>> ...
```

I can also add/remove the role fine in other commands/on ready
but when I try to create/delete - mostly delete - it gives me the error in on_guild_join

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    test_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='test-role')
    if test_role:
        await test_role.delete()
    else:
        test_role = await guild.create_role(name='test-role')
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the bot is above the role you're trying to delete.
EX:

```
Owner
Co-Owner
**test-role**
**The Bots Role**
```

^^^ The Bot role would need to be placed above the test-role.

I believe it's a Discord Hierarchy issue